# Importing FBX into Blender 2.9 results in warped mesh

Tags: animation, import, .fbx

I'm new to Blender and want to try to edit an animated fbx file. Upon import the Rig is looking good and is animating fine, the mesh however is warped beyond recognition. How do I go about fixing this. Will I have to disconnect it from the bones and repaint all the weights or am I missing something? I've been playing with the fbx import settings but couldn't find one that would import good.

The model is supposed to be a bird, I noticed that the helper objects are also quite a bit off...

[image: Stork imported]
Best,
-martin

Comment: None of the posted solutions will work here!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I'll share what I've been able to find on it. Its caused by an error with the skeleton. If you delete it, the mesh should fix itself. Apparently blender just doesn't support importing skeletons/armatures from FBX, but third parties do.

There is a workaround - https://darisl.wordpress.com/about/importing-fbx-files-into-blender-with-full-armaturesweights/

And software you can purchase - https://blendermarket.com/products/better-fbx-importer--exporter

I have yet to verify either.